# how to add tools to python

Tags: python, msp430, mingw-w64, mspgcc

I installed python in Win7. I need to add python-msp430-tools 0.6 to my python.
Hence I downloaded python-msp430-tools 0.6 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-msp430-tools . But there is a problem? How can I add this tool to my python.

(By the way, I downloaded msp-gcc for mingw and fixed PATH.)

I will appreciate any help.

Best Regards.

Comment: Have you considered finding some resources regarding on how to install packages on https://pypi.python.org/pypi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'easy_install' script from your $PYTHON_PATH/bin folder. Like:

```
easy_install python-msp430-tools
```

It will download package from pypi and install it. You dont have to download it by hand. You also can use `pip` in the same way after installing it. So once:

```
easy_install pip
```

Then:

```
pip install python-msp430-tools
```

Pip is much better in package management.

Answer (score 0):

for installing packages from pypi it is better to use pip in my idea.
take a look at [python on windows](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win.html)